# Where to publish a new pathological function?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, soft-question, publishing

Soft-question here: I have discovered a new family of functions that could be considered as pathological. These are some of their properties:

- They are almost everywhere continuous. They have a countable infinite number of discontinuities (and so they are Riemann integrable).
- The set $\{: \; \text{discontinuous at } \}$ is dense in the domain.
- The graph is non-connected.
- $f(f(x))= x$

I can prove all of this, but my problem es that I don't know if this is relevant or even interesting. And also, I would like to publish it, but I am a researcher in systems biology, and I don't know which are the journals that could be interested in this work. Could you help me, please?

Many thanks in advance!

---

EDIT: I have summarised the appreciations made by Mark S and Mark Kamsma in the comments.

Comment: Property 1 implies 3. And 5 implies 2. 1 doesn't imply 4 but 4 often holds when 1 does so it doesn't seem notable. The *continuous* solutions to Babbage's functional equation (the one in 5) are well understood, but I don't know enough to know whether it would be hard to find a solution with countably many discontinues.

Comment: Actually, let $g:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be your favorite bijection with countably many discontinues. Then I think $g^{-1}\circ (-\mathrm{id})\circ g$ would generally satisfy all properties in the OP. Let me know if there's something I'm missing, though.

Comment: @MarkS. There is some statement about denseness though. Although I am not entirely sure what is meant as it is written: "the $x$ such that $f(x)$ is a discontinuity are dense". Literally that would mean that $\{x : f \text{ discontinuous at } f(x)\}$ is dense, but I suspect OP actually means that $\{x : f \text{ discontinuous at } x\}$ is dense.

Comment: Many thanks for your appreciations. I wrote this in the metro and in a hurry. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Now I am thinking that under the new set of characteristics, 1+2 imply 3. Doesn't it?

Comment: If this were my result and if I thought might be publishable I would look up the list of mathematicians on the faculty of a university to see what their specialties are (In this case, I would look for Analysis) and send this Q (verbatim) by e-mail.